# Alpaca Data Object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a python 3.6 script to use with the Alpaca trading API.  I am trying to isolate price data for stocks from a json output.  I cannot get the stock price put into a variable.

Code:

```
quote = api.polygon.last_trade('AAPL')
print (quote)
b = quote['price']
print (b)
```

Output:

```
Trade({'exchange': 4, 'price': 227.08, 'size': 88, 'timestamp': 1570233584825})
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "AAPL.py", line 24, in <module>
b = quote['price']
TypeError: 'Trade' object is not subscriptable
```

I am trying to get the 227.08 into variable b.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can do `quote.price` instead of using the square bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
getattr(quote, 'price')
```