# Accessing data from this List

Tags: python-3.x, list, api

When I run the api request below it returns a list. I am new to python and I tried looking up methods to extract the symbols from this list, but I have not been successful. I seem to run into an issue with Asset and typical get "'Asset' object is not subscriptable".

```
active_assets = api.list_assets(status='active')

nasdaq_assets = [a for a in active_assets if a.exchange == 'NASDAQ']

print(nasdaq_assets)

[({Asset({   'class': 'us_equity',
'easy_to_borrow': True,
'exchange': 'NASDAQ',
'id': '5c01547a-ef31-4984-ac51-89732fcc412f',
'marginable': True,
'name': 'Zynga Inc. Class A Common Stock',
'shortable': True,
'status': 'active',
'symbol': 'ZNGA',
'tradable': True}), Asset({   'class': 'us_equity',
'easy_to_borrow': True,
'exchange': 'NASDAQ',
'id': 'a2bbc790-eeeb-442d-a3f2-3b1e2a92be1b',
'marginable': True,
'name': 'Zentalis Pharmaceuticals, Inc. Common Stock',
'shortable': True,
'status': 'active',
'symbol': 'ZNTL',
'tradable': True}), Asset({   'class': 'us_equity',
'easy_to_borrow': True,
'exchange': 'NASDAQ',
'id': '8b059378-e1d0-422c-b80e-157b34700dd6',
'marginable': True,
'name': 'Zscaler, Inc. Common Stock',
'status': 'active',
'symbol': 'ZS',
'tradable': True}), Asset({   'class': 'us_equity',
'easy_to_borrow': False,
'exchange': 'NASDAQ',
'id': '89f81d13-e13b-4233-9749-26eeb7c82ed8',
'marginable': True,
'name': 'Zosano Pharma Corporation Common Stock',
'shortable': False,
'status': 'active',
'symbol': 'ZSAN',
'tradable': True}), Asset({   'class': 'us_equity',
'easy_to_borrow': True,
'exchange': 'NASDAQ',
'id': 'bd960cb2-83a3-4618-aa09-fc7b6d88e4b2',
'marginable': True,
'name': 'Zumiez Inc. Common Stock',
'shortable': True,
'status': 'active',
'symbol': 'ZUMZ',
'tradable': True})]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alpaca Data Object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58263928/alpaca-data-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method

```
for obj in nasdaq_assets:
    for attr in obj.__dict__:
        print(obj.__dict__[attr])
```

Let me know if this worked or not

Comment: This worked! I just needed to add ['symbol'] to print(obj.__dict__[attr]). Thank you! print(obj.__dict__[attr] ['symbol'])